# What is the procedure of creating a new Wordpress website when I have already created one

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have wordpress installed on my localhost server running with XAMPP. I have already created one website and now I am have to create another one. What is the procedure of setting up a new website. Do I create a new database on phpmyadmin, as well as a new user? When I installed wordpress for the first time I added a website name and some user credentials to login to this site, so do I have to install wordpress again?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to develop a new Wordpress website locally, I would suggest creating a distinct MySQL database and user for this new site. Then, create an Apache virtual host (vhost) in your XAMP setup. You will then have two separate instances of Wordpress for your two different websites.

You can also avoid creating a new vhost by installing Wordpress in a subfolder of your initial site, example : `/website2/`

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have to download and install wordpress every time you want to create a new website. Also you create a database for each website.